# Inconsistence with R's "Residual Standard Error" (in lm) in case of WLS

Tags: r, regression, transformation, glm, weighted

I am trying to reproduce Weighted Least Squares (WLS) in Excel using R for confirmation. I use the (trivial but reproducible) following dataset to perform a double check :

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y<-c(9,23,30,42,54,66)
w<-1/x
```

When I calculate a WLS using lm and the weight argument as follows :

```
WLS<-lm(y~x, weights = w)
summary(WLS)
```

The output is :

```
> summary(WLS)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, weights = w)

Weighted Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.50162  1.67280 -1.02017 -0.44984 -0.01447  0.34087 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -1.6311     1.2241  -1.333    0.254    
x            11.1327     0.4181  26.627 1.18e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.05 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9944,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.993 
F-statistic:   709 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 1.182e-05
```

I have read [here](https://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/explaining-the-lm-summary-in-r/#:%7E:text=the%20summary%20output.-,Residual%20Standard%20Error,1%20%2B%20%23%20of%20variables%20involved.) that the Residual standard error as calculated from R can be calculated manually using the following lines (adapted to the above model for convenience) :

```
k=length(WLS$coefficients)-1 #Subtract one to ignore intercept
SSE=sum(WLS$residuals**2)
n=length(WLS$residuals)
sqrt(SSE/(n-(1+k))) #Residual Standard Error
```

This calculation is consistent with the formula I have seen in many books ([e.g. here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485165/understanding-rseresidual-standard-error)). However, when running this manual calculation, the result returned is `1.618487` (i.e. not 1.05).

I found namely [here](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/canty/teaching/stat3a03/Lectures7.pdf) that WLS can also be performed by applying OLS to transformed variables (model in matrix notation: Y'=X'B+e') using the transformation : Y=W^(1/2)Y ; X'=W^(1/2)X ; e'=W^(1/2)e. I perfomed it in R with the following code :

```
v<-w^(1/2)
x2<-x*v
y2<-y*v
WLS2<-lm(y2~0+v+x2)
```

i.e. model with intercept forecd to zero, v represents the new intercept. Doing so, I get the following output :

```
> summary(WLS2)

Call:
lm(formula = y2 ~ 0 + v + x2)

Residuals:
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
-0.50162  1.67280 -1.02017 -0.44984 -0.01447  0.34087 

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
v   -1.6311     1.2241  -1.333    0.254    
x2  11.1327     0.4181  26.627 1.18e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.05 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9982,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9972 
F-statistic:  1085 on 2 and 4 DF,  p-value: 3.388e-06
```

Note that the regression coefficients and Residual standard error are the same but the R², F -statistic and residuals are different. Also, I do get `1.049927` when I calculate the Residual standard error with the residuals of that model (WLS2).

My question : can someone kindly explain why the Residual standard error returned by R are the same for the two models despite having different residuals ? Is it correct that the Residual standard error should be `1.618487` (as calculated manually) for the first model (without data transformation) ? Is that a problem with how R internally computes WLS ? It seems that R omits to back-transform residuals prior to calculate the Residual standard error.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that the Residual standard error should be 1.618487 (as calculated manually) for the first model (without data transformation) ?

No because you fitted a model with weights but then forgot about the weights in your computation of sigma.

```r
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y <- c(9, 23, 30, 42, 54, 66)
w <- 1 / x

WLS <- lm(y ~ x, weights = w)
summary(WLS)$sigma
#> [1] 1.049927

# You computed sigma for lm(y ~ x)
k <- length(WLS$coefficients) - 1 # Subtract one to ignore intercept
SSE <- sum(WLS$residuals**2)
n <- length(WLS$residuals)
sqrt(SSE / (n - (1 + k))) # Residual Standard Error, without weighting
#> [1] 1.618487

# But what you really wanted is to compute sigma for lm (y ~ x | weights = w)
SSE <- sum(w * (WLS$residuals)**2)
sqrt(SSE / (n - (1 + k))) # Residual Standard Error, with weighting
#> [1] 1.049927
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

> Why the Residual standard error returned by R are the same for the two models despite having different residuals ?

It's because the second model explicitly includes the weights:

- WLS:  *y ~ 1 + x* with weights = w
- WLS2: *sqrt(w) * y ~ sqrt(w) + sqrt(w) * x* with weights = 1